# How can I correct my regular expression in Java?

Tags: java, regex

I met a problem when I try to extract a segment from a string using Java. The original string is looks like `test/data/20/0000893220-97-000850.txt`, and I want to extract the segment which is behind the third `/`.

My regular expression is like

```
String m_str = "test/data/20/0000893220-97-000850.txt";
Pattern reg = Pattern.compile("[.*?].txt");
Matcher matcher = reg.matcher(m_str);
System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
```

The expected result is `0000893220-97-000850`, but obviously, I failed. How can I correct this?

Comment: Try `[^/.]+(?=\\.txt)`

Comment: [Try This one](https://regex101.com/r/zX7eQ3/1)

Comment: You have two answers @beepretty - any good?

Comment: Thanks! I tried both them, and finally I find using "[0-9]*+[-]+[0-9]*+[-]+[0-9]*" can do that.

Answer (score 1):

`[^\/]+$`

https://regex101.com/r/tS4nS2/2

This will extract the last segment in a string that contains after slashes. It would work great if you want that, as opposed to *only* the third section.

To find and extract the match, you don't need a match group (hence, no `()`), however, you need to instruct the matcher to only look for the pattern, since `.matches()` will attempt to compare the entire string. Here is the relevant bit and [here is a full example](https://ideone.com/Y8gg1c):

```
matcher.find(); //finds any occurrence of the pattern in the string
System.out.println(matcher.group()); //returns the entire occurence
```

Note the lack of index inside the call `.group()`.

On a separate note, in Java, you don't necessarily need regex - extracting the last part can be done using plain Java

```
String matched = m_str.split('/')[2];
```

This would capture the third segment while

```
String[] matches = m_str.split('/');
String matched = matches[matches.length-1];
```

Would give you the last part.